# Relationship between conditional expected values

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

For a random variable $X \ge 0$ and a parameter $t \ge 0$ consider $E[X | X \ge t]$ and $E[X| X < t]$.

Is there anything one could derive about the relationship between $E[X]$, $E[X | X \ge t]$ and $E[X| X < t]$?

Edit: I came up with $E[X] = p(X \ge t)* E[X| X \ge t] + p(X < t)* E[X| X < t]$  which feels painfully obvious... Is there anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E[X\mid X\in A]:=\frac{\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\in A\}}]}{\mathbb P\{X\in A\}}.$$

Comment: I assume you wanted to hint towards my edit? :)